# In SQL, how to get the value of the next row that satisfies a condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table x with the following columns

```
Message  TimeEvent   TriggerValue  TimeStamp
 m1         t1           1          2017-10-18 13:28:43.993
 m1         t1           1          2017-10-18 13:28:53.787
 m1         t1           1          2017-10-18 13:29:53.787
                         0          2017-10-18 13:30:53.787
```

If I want to find the duration of the time(difference in time between TimeStamp when Triggervalue is 0 and t1) when the TriggerValue was 1, how can I do it...like if I have to return

```
m1   t1  duration
```

Something like when I am in line 3, if line 4 Triggervalue is 0, then I subtract TimeStamp and t1. I feel like I need to use the LEAD function, but don't know how to use it with where clause .

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what are the exact and complete desired results for your example data?

Comment: Are you trying to find the difference in time between one row and the next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your requirement is a little vague, DDL, sample data and the desired output makes it much easier for us to help you. Have a look at this [article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/) for more details.

To get a duration we need a start and end date we need to be able to group by something. For my solution below I'll be grouping by message. For duration I'll assume you're looking for seconds; if not, it will be easy to adjust.

LEAD (& LAG) will not help you because they use static values to say how many rows to go ahead or back to. E.g. `LAG(col1, 1)`  to say "previous row" or LEAD(col1, 5) to say "five rows ahead." You can't, however, say, "give me the next row where the value is "x". Note this example:

```
declare @table table (someNbr int);
insert @table(someNbr) values (5),(10),(12),(15),(20);

select 
  someNbr, 
  PreviousRow  = LAG(someNbr,1) over (order by someNbr),
  twoRowsBack  = LAG(someNbr,2) over (order by someNbr),
    [ |]            = '|',
  someNbr, 
    nextRow      = LEAD(someNbr,1) over (order by someNbr),
  twoRowsAhead = LEAD(someNbr,2) over (order by someNbr)
from @table;
```

**Results**:

```
someNbr     PreviousRow twoRowsBack  |   someNbr     nextRow     twoRowsAhead
----------- ----------- ----------- ---- ----------- ----------- ------------
5           NULL        NULL        |    5           10          12
10          5           NULL        |    10          12          15
12          10          5           |    12          15          20
15          12          10          |    15          20          NULL
20          15          12          |    20          NULL        NULL
```

What you are looking for can be handled with simple grouping or partitioning. Here's what I put together:

**Sample data**

```
if object_id('tempdb..#x') is not null drop table #x;
select * into #x 
from (values 
('m2', 't1', 1, '2017-10-18 11:26:43.222'), 
('m2', 't1', 1, '2017-10-18 11:28:52.780'),
('m2', 't1', 1, '2017-10-18 11:29:53.709'),
('m2', 't1', 0, '2017-10-18 11:31:53.781'),
('m1', 't1', 1, '2017-10-18 13:28:43.993'), 
('m1', 't1', 1, '2017-10-18 13:28:53.787'),
('m1', 't1', 1, '2017-10-18 13:29:53.787'),
('m1', 't1', 0, '2017-10-18 13:30:53.787'))
v([Message], [TimeEvent], TriggerValue, [TimeStamp]);

create clustered index uq_cl_x on #x([Message], [TimeStamp]);
```

**My solution**

```
select [Message], [TimeEvent], Duration = datediff(second, minTime, maxTime)
from 
(
  select [Message], [TimeEvent], 
    rn      = row_number() over (partition by [message] order by [timestamp]),
    minTime = min(timeStamp) over (partition by [message] order by [timeStamp]),
    maxTime = max(case TriggerValue when 0 then [timestamp] end) over (partition by [Message] order by (select 1))
  from #x
) x
where rn=1;
```

**Results**

```
Message TimeEvent Duration
------- --------- -----------
m1      t1        130
m2      t1        310
```

A couple things to note:
1. I'm using ROW_NUMBER to get distinct values without a sort in the execution plan (better for performance). I could get the same results by getting rid of the row_number logic and using DISTINCT instead but it will be slower. 
2. There are ORDER BY statements in my window clauses (e.g. `minTime = min(timeStamp) over (partition by [message] order by [timeStamp])` ); These are not required but will also improve performance as well.

Comment: Thank you..this is what I needed

Answer (score -1):

So long as the Timestamp column has a Datetime data type you can just subtract them from one another. You will need a way of identifying which of the three timestamps where Triggervalue is 1 you're subtracting so I put ID = 3 for this example.

```
SELECT
(
SELECT timestamp  from x where Triggervalue = 0
)
-
(
SELECT timestamp from x where Triggervalue = 1 AND ID = 3
)
```